# How to run a music bot on replit (discord.py)

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py, youtube-dl, replit

I'm making a music bot for my discord server and I want it to run 24/7 on repl.it but when I run it on my computer I add `executable="./ffmpeg.exe"` to the from_probe function. Nevertheless, replit doesn't support executable files so I need to find an other way to make this work. I tried installing ffmpeg package, I also looked up for tutorials how to use ffmpeg-python with youtube_dl. None of these worked. If you need some additional info, just ask me in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible on replit. FFmpeg was working on replit before, it does not work now, you possibly could find another module to play music.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).